# Test-driven development for JSPs specifically

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, tdd

I've been writing test-driven code even before understanding what TDD actually was. Calling functions and classes without having its implementation helps me understand and build my application in a much faster and efficient way. So I'm very used the process of writing code->compiling it->seeing it fail->fixing it by building its implementation.

This process is a bit harder for the Web. Specifically JSPs. When I compile my Java classes, all it's fine, I can see the compile errors. However seeing errors in the JSPs require me to open a browser and call that specific JSP.

Is there a way to avoid this process and show me the JSP compile errors without actually loading up a browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically don't test JSPs directly. It's generally a good idea to keep as little logic in your JSPs as possible, and if you're JSPs only contain a few `<c:out>` tags then there's not really too much to test. However, if you do have a fair amount of logic within them then what I would do is extract that logic into a custom tag, which you can test drive pretty easily.

Comment: you're right... jsps shouldn't contain logic in the first place

Answer (score 3):

Sure. You can pre-compile JSP. There is even ant task that does it. Please refer to link: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jspc.html

But I think that this is only first step. This will allow you to see compilation errors. I think that you wanted more, i.e. unit tests. I believe that tools like Jakarta Cactus (or others) may help you.

BTW recently I found the following [resource](http://java-source.net/open-source/testing-tools) that enumerates a huge number of java testing tools.

Comment: +1 JspC isn't just an ant task, it's a shell for Tomcat's built-in JSP->servlet compiler, which you can use as part of any build environment. @Luca: Even if you aren't using Tomcat as your JEE server, it could well be a handy tool in your process: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/jasper/JspC.html

Comment: "2011/08/05 - Jakarta Cactus has been retired."

Answer (score 1):

Compiling is the easy part, and I think AlexR's answer handles it fine.

Testing and test-driving JSP is difficult, as testing it really requires deploying to a web container or simulating (mocking) this, and running through a browser or something mimicking a browser.

[Cactus](http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/) can help with in-container testing.  [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) can as well.

Or you can mock the environment.  If you're using [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/), it has some good support for doing so.

But the best way to deal with the difficulty of testing and test-driving JSP is to stop using JSP altogether, or to at least minimize the logic in your JSP code by avoiding scriptlets.

Since a JSP is just a servlet in disguise, it's always possible to write web applications without JSP, and there are options using frameworks like [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) and [Tapestry](http://tapestry.apache.org/) or template engines like [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) to make Java web application development without JSP pretty easy.