# I've inherited a JSP/Java Servlet web-app, can I JUnit test this (in Tomcat) to get the code coverage?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, junit

Happy Friday!  I assume somebody out there has a simple answer to this question and I'm hoping you read this post.  I haven't really found the answer that ***I want*** searching the tubes & StackOverflow today.

I've inherited a web-app (version 2.4) that runs in Tomcat 5.5 and I want to run code coverage and JUnit tests on this to see what's really being used (I believe much of it's been deprecated) and what can be improved.  I'm using Eclipse, I'd like to use EclEmma and I'd like to run these tests inside Tomcat because of some online resources the web app uses for data.

Does anyone have a tutorial or suggestion on how I might accomplish this?

Comment: Did it come with the JUnit tests? Are you planning to write them anew?

Comment: @Olaf - It did not come with JUnit tests and I do plan to write them.  I've used JUnit in the past, but that environment _was_ setup for me, so I need to brush up on the testing framework too. Have you tested in a Servlet container before?

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296315/test-driven-development-for-jsps-specifically help?

Comment: @JoseK Not entirely, but thanks for the link.  You see, it's not really that I want to test the View (JSP's), more that I want to use the View to invoke methods and "test" the whole system.  This app relies on some other WAR's running in Tomcat for things like Authentication and data.  My other thought was that I could test everything and get an EclEmma coverage report to make sure anything deprecated has been removed properly.  I do keep running into Jakarta Cactus in my search for a solution, but @Olaf's JUnitEE suggestion looks good too.  I've yet to try it, but I'll report back soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite hard to unit test a servlet/jsp application which was not designed with testability in mind. I was working with dependency injection frameworks and test-driven development for last 7 years or so. Before that I once had to retrofit a servlet/jsp application with the unit tests. I believe I used JUnitEE for that purpose. I was not using code coverage tools at the time, so I'm not sure if it would have worked with them. Then again, it probably improved greatly since I used it last time.

Comment: I verified and the project I mentioned above is still alive and deployed at several dozen locations. It is indeed unit tested using JUnitEE. The team currently supporting it is also looking at Jakarta Cactus for the purpose of running unit tests.

Comment: that's very cool.  Thanks for the link, I'm reading and researching JUnitEE now.  I wish I were still working with a good Dependency Injection framework and TDD (Spring), but as I said I inherited some code so it's time to step back in time 10 years (though... I'd be in high school if I did that).  JUnitEE looks pretty good, I may have to give you the check-mark for the answer.  I might wait a day or two to see if any others are offered though :)

Comment: You get the points, I haven't used this yet, but I will!  I'm writing a prototype now and as soon as Thursday my first iteration will likely start.  Thanks for linking to this as it didn't come up in any of my searching for keywords like "Tomcat junit jsp" etc. 

Thanks so much