# Handle to test object in JUnit4

Tags: java, servlets, junit4, test-runner, data-hiding

In my specific test case, I need to over-ride the dependencies of my test case to inject more dependencies like servlet request and response.

It is not possible to mock these as my API requires an actual servlet container to compile and run JSP's.

How can I get a handle to the test instance using JUnit 4?

I have tried over-riding `createTest()` in `BlockJUnit4Runner` (which works), but then the same behavior cannot be extended to `Parameterized` tests, because the runner used by such tests are internal and not visible in the hierarchy.

Comment: Can you post an example test?

Comment: Have you looked at JUnitEE? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390056/ive-inherited-a-jsp-java-servlet-web-app-can-i-junit-test-this-in-tomcat-to/6390794#6390794

Comment: @Olaf: I am bound to use JUnit - not possible to migrate to a different framework at this point.